# Como alterar a extensão de arquivos de forma recursiva no GNU/Linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou tentando pegar todos os arquivos `.sql` do meu projeto e alterar a extensão para `.md`.

Já consegui fazer isso, porém, os arquivos estão sendo movidos para a raiz do sistema, que é o *path* onde o script Shell está. Como renomear mantendo o arquivo original no mesmo diretório?

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*.sql; do
    mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .sql).md"
done
```

Comment: Tem o comando `rename` também, da uma olhada https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente poderia usar `$(dirname $file)` para pegar o caminho da pasta do arquivo atual no loop

```
for file in ./**/*.sql; do
    mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "$file" .sql).md"
done
```

Comment: Top, seria possível também considerar mais de uma extensão? Tipo, aplicar a mesma regra (condição) para extensão `.sql`, `.pl` e `.txt`?

Comment: @FábioJânio Nesse caso, vc poderia fazer outro `for` externo com as extensões (`for ext in .sql .pl .txt; do (faz o for acima com $ext)`)

Comment: Caro @FábioJânio tem sim, mas ai o assunto é diferente, seria legal criar uma pergunta só para esta nova duvida especifica.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz um "gato" aqui e acho que funcionou: `for file in ./**/*.sql ./**/*.ora; do
    mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "$file" ."${file##*.}").md"
    # mv $file "${file%.sql}.md"
done`

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que `basename` retira a informação da pasta e retorna apenas o nome do arquivo. Então a ideia é não usá-lo, para que esta informação não se perca.

Para manipular o nome do arquivo, você pode usar a sintaxe `${var%pattern}`, [que remove o *pattern* do valor de `var`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF):

```
for file in ./**/*.sql; do
    mv $file "${file%.sql}.md"
done
```

`${file%.sql}` remove o trecho ".sql" do nome do arquivo e em seguida `.md` adiciona esta string ao nome. Ou seja, a extensão é trocada de `.sql` para `.md`.